# Fullcalendar - Create listDay on a specific date

Tags: fullcalendar, fullcalendar-5

I'm doing some tests with the FullCalendar tool and I have an idea but can't find how to do it.

I'm playing with this demo from the ListView doc page : https://codepen.io/pen?editors=0010

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  var calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');

  var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
    initialView: 'listDay',
    headerToolbar: {
      left: 'title',
      center: '',
      right: ''
    },
    events: 'https://fullcalendar.io/api/demo-feeds/events.json'
  });

  calendar.render();
});
```

Is it possible to load the "listDay" on a specific day instead of the actual day ?

Comment: If you mean how to start the calendar on a specific date, then see the initialDate option: https://fullcalendar.io/docs/initialDate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the solution is to add an initialDate:'' in the parameters

Thank you @ADyson